# Android: can I have a browsable service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest, intentfilter

I want my service to be able to be called from the browser when the user presses a button.
I've tried defining it like this, as I would do with an activity but it doesn't work.

```
<service
  android:name=".services.MyService"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:exported="true" >
  <intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="my.scheme" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I've read that one way to achieve what I want is to make an activity browsable, call the service from it and immediately call `finish()`. Is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

> I want my service to be able to be called from the browser when the user presses a button

Browsers are not going to do that.

> I've tried defining it like this, as I would do with an activity but it doesn't work.

Browsers are calling `startActivity()`, not `startService()`.

> I've read that one way to achieve what I want is to make an activity browsable, call the service from it and immediately call finish(). Is there another way?

Not in general. There may be possibilities with browser plugins, but that would require users to install the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Which plugins are you talking about?

Comment: @Fabio: I am talking about a plugin that you would write, that would trigger a `startService()` call.